# found index 0, size is 0 in android

Tags: android

"There i found index out of bound exception how can i solve???"

```
public static void addToCart() {
ArrayList<ItemData> iArr;
if (holdSelection != null) {
String categoryID = holdSelection.getCategoryID();
int position = categoriesAddedd.indexOf(holdSelection.getCategoryID());
int itemPosition =categoriesitemAddedd.indexOf(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getItemID());
if (!categoriesAddedd.contains(categoryID)) {
    CategoryData data = new CategoryData();
            data.setCategoryID(categoryID);
            data.setCategoryName(holdSelection.getCategoryName());
            data.setItemData(holdSelection.getItemData());
            mAddedToCart.add(data);
            categoriesAddedd.add(categoryID);   categoriesitemAddedd.add(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getItemID());
Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.Add_to_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
} else {
if (position>=0) {
if(itemPosition>=0){
if(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getScaled()){
Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.Already_in_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}else{
Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.Already_in_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
}else{
try{
CategoryData data = mAddedToCart.get(position);             
                     iArr = data.getItemData();
                     iArr.add(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0));                  
                    categoriesAddedd.add(categoryID);
categoriesitemAddedd.add(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getItemID());
Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.Add_to_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                       
}catch (Exception e) {
// TODO: handle exception
Toast.makeText(mContext, "There is " +e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();                     
System.out.println("Exception : "+ e.getMessage());
e.printStackTrace();                
}       
}
}
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's impossible to help without a minimum of (structured) information (and also without a Hello, please, tank you, polite words if you prefer).

First of all, you have to use the brackets to display code when you post, so your clean code should appear as follow :

```
public static void addToCart() { 
ArrayList iArr; 

    if (holdSelection != null) { 
    String categoryID = holdSelection.getCategoryID(); 
    int position = categoriesAddedd.indexOf(holdSelection.getCategoryID()); 
    int itemPosition =categoriesitemAddedd.indexOf(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getItemID()); 

        if (!categoriesAddedd.contains(categoryID)) { 
            CategoryData data = new CategoryData(); 
            data.setCategoryID(categoryID); 
            data.setCategoryName(holdSelection.getCategoryName()); 
            data.setItemData(holdSelection.getItemData()); 
            mAddedToCart.add(data); 
            categoriesAddedd.add(categoryID); 
            categoriesitemAddedd.add(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getItemID()); 
            Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.Add_to_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
        } else { 
            if (position>=0) { 
                if(itemPosition>=0){ 
                    if(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getScaled()){ 
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.Already_in_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    }else{ 
                        Toast.makeText(mContext,R.string.Already_in_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show(); 
                    } 
                }else{ 
                    try{ 
                        CategoryData data = mAddedToCart.get(position);
                        iArr = data.getItemData(); iArr.add(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0));
                        categoriesAddedd.add(categoryID); 
                        categoriesitemAddedd.add(holdSelection.getItemData().get(0).getItemID()); 
                        Toast.makeText(mContext, R.string.Add_to_cart,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e) 
                    { // TODO: handle exception Toast.makeText(mContext, "There is " +e,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        System.out.println("Exception : "+ e.getMessage()); e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                } 
            } 
        }       
    } 
}
```

then my first question will be : what is holdSelection related to?
Please add more parts of your code as your log (asked by Remees).

Alex.

Comment: In which row do you get this Exception. Please post your log.

Comment: I reformat the owner's ticket code and I get a minus 1, that's weard :s. For the log, I asked to Ashish (who initially posted here). If he wants more help, he got to give us more details.

Comment: I guess because your answer does not solve the problem but explains it better. But for another user with the same problem this answer is useless (no offense, good effort on your part)

Comment: Ho ok, no problem :). The fact is that I just can't comment at this time (maybe later), once again, please Ashish provide us with more details in order for us to help and maybe solve your problem.

Comment: @Alexandre Niceties like "Hello", "Please", "Thanks in advance" are extraneous information and frequently deleted from posts. Stack tries to get straight to the point. "This is my problem, this is what I have tried" sort of questions.